# Is Visual Studio Express suitable for commercial application development?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

If I were to develop a Silverlight game and publish it to a site where you can play it for free is the use considered to be commercial or personal?

What about if the site has adverts on, is it then considered to be commercial if the program is free but its hosted on a site that makes money?

My reason for asking this is Visual Studio Express can only be used for personal or non-commercial use so I want to check what the limits for the use are.

Comment: "Visual Studio Express can only be used for personal or non-commercial use" --- This is not correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question about a software tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Express editions of Visual Studio allow commercial use, so this is not a problem, one way or another.

I believe the only commercial use not allowed is using VS Express in a hosting service.

The original FAQ article that said so seems to have gone AWOL and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/e471aff6-90fd-432b-8388-0d9a65a394b0) forum thread seems to be the next best thing (thanks @Anna Lear).

Comment: This used to be mentioned in the VS Express FAQ, but that doesn't seem to exist anymore. The best supporting reference I can find is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/e471aff6-90fd-432b-8388-0d9a65a394b0).

Comment: Previous versions disallowed commercial use, which is probably where the confusion stems from.

Comment: @AnnaLear and Oded thanks, i read somewhere that express could only be used for personal or non-commercial so i guess that information was wrong.

Comment: @Manatherin - As tdammers commented, it used to be the case. But I believe it was dropped with VS 2008+.